# Developer access to Komfo

Tags: social-connected

Beginning with Sitecore 8.0, the Social Connected module became part of the main platform, and it now requires access to the third-party Komfo service. When a user clicks on the Social button on the Sitecore Dashboard, she is prompted to log on to Komfo, either with a Komfo account or with Google/Facebook.

I attempted to log in with both of these social services, but received this message: "You don't have access to our platform with the following accounts."  There is no way to create a Komfo account; the only option presented is to "request a demo".

[image: Komfo prompt]

Is there a way to obtain a developer account? This is a significant barrier to developer discovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, Sitecore/Komfo doesn't offer developer accounts yet.  If you're aligned with a Sitecore Partner, the partner can get an account from their partner rep.  That's how we got ours.